# Spring MVC force Jackson to only use setters

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring MVC application which uses Jackson and the @RequestBody annotation.

I have a field in the POJO that I do not want Jackson to map, so I have lombok set the setter access level to NONE.

```
@NotNull
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private boolean enabled = false;
```

I have tried to force Spring's ObjectMapper bean to only use setters by configuring as:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
    return mapper;
}
```

I would assume that with no setter and no visability of the field Jackson would not map up the "enabled" field... but if I send a body with enabled set to true it maps it,

Can anyone advise what else I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to prevent the field from getting deserialised from json and serialised? Or just deserialised?

Comment: @Strelok I just want to stop it from being deserialised, I still want it to go back out on a response I just don't want the user to have any control over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just annotate the field with `@JsonProperty` and set access to read only.

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private boolean enabled;
```

PS. You don't need to annotate with `@NotNull` or initialise to false since you're using a primitive type.